# Exclude specific subdirectory from mod_rewrite rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have:

```
RewriteRule ^scripts/(.*\.js) /combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1
```

Current scripts folder looks like:

```
scripts/
    folder1
        f1.css
    folder2
        f2.css
    folder3
        f3.css
    bespoke
        bespoke.css
    css.ss
```

I would like this rule to exclude anything within the scripts/bespoke/ folder. Any suggestions? (I am useless at regex and new to mod rewrite, should I be using a RewriteCond?)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `RewriteCond` condition:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^bespoke/
RewriteRule ^scripts/(.*\.js) /combine.php?type=javascript&files=$1
```